# can I deploy .net app as managed application in azure partner portal?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

can I deploy .net application(software as service app) as managed application in azure partner portal ?
I am trying to give details using json zip file but not accepted ,
pls help..
ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/publish-service-catalog-app

Comment: please provide additional error details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can deploy. You have to create a package as ZIP file containing ARM template for the portal UI definition createuidefinition.json and maintemplate.json. You can put your web app published zip into any server location (azure storage or something else) and create an arm template to deploy this zip into azure. You then need to submit this to cloud partner portal. If you still stuck into this then I can provide you the complete package file to deploy your app. You just need to change your file path to submit your app to cloud partner portal.
You can refer GitHub for a sample managed app solution for azure marketplace.
See [GitHub link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-managedapp-samples/tree/master/samples/201-managed-web-app)